# Github Security - Public Project

Tags: git, github

I have a simple question, can people change my code on GitHub on a public project? Is my code safe in a repo?  I know its a simple question but I need to make sure I'm not going to wake up to my code being fowled up!

Answer (score 2):

With a public repo on Github, anyone can see your code. They can also fork it and modify their forks. However, they won't have permissions to change your repo.

So as far as security means "my code won't change without my permission", you're safe.